Pass math function formula to lua function
I have this lua code which calculate values of math function (polynomial) at specific numbers, I have defined a lua function (fvalues) with three arguments and I need to add another argument for function formula (I couldn't find a way to add it), any help to achieve this is appreciated.
What I need is to add an argument to fvalues function (func) which allow user to change polynomial fonction every time he wants in his document, for example fvalues(x^2+1,1,0.5,5).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
local function trim0( s )
    return string.format("%g", s)
end

-- fvalues(func,ini,step,nb)
function  fvalues(ini,step,nb)
    local cell={}
    local result={}
    local x=ini
    for i=1,nb do
    cell[i]= x
    result[i]= x^2-3*x+1 -- func
    x=x+ step
    end

    tex.print("\\begin{center}\\begin{tblr}{colspec={*{99}{c}},vlines,hlines,rows={.8cm},column{2-Z}={.8cm},column{1}={bg=blue!20}}")
    tex.print("$x$")
    for i=1, nb do
    tex.print("&"..trim0(cell[i]))
    end
    tex.print("\\\\")
    tex.print("$x^2-3x+1$") -- tex.print("$".. func.."$")
    for i=1, nb do
    tex.print("&"..trim0(result[i]))
    end
    tex.print("\\\\\\end{tblr}\\end{center}")
end    
\end{luacode} 


\begin{document} 

\directlua{fvalues(-3,.5,6)}

% \directlua{fvalues(x^2+1,-3,.5,6)}

\end{document}


the posted code gives lua errors, comment is --  not # in Lua

Lua has the load() function that turns a string argument into executable code, similar to eval() in other languages. The code that you load must return something, so you can use
load("return "..func)
The resulting function can use variables but only if they are global, so instead of local x=ini you need just x=ini.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
local function trim0( s )
    return string.format("%g", s)
end

function fvalues(func,ini,step,nb)
    local cell={}
    local result={}
    x=ini
    local myfunc = load("return "..func)
    for i=1,nb do
    cell[i]= x
    result[i]= myfunc()
    x=x+ step
    end

    tex.print("\\begin{center}\\begin{tblr}{colspec={*{99}{c}},vlines,hlines,rows={.8cm},column{2-Z}={.8cm},column{1}={bg=blue!20}}")
    tex.print("$x$")
    for i=1, nb do
    tex.print("&"..trim0(cell[i]))
    end
    tex.print("\\\\")
    tex.print("$".. func.."$")
    for i=1, nb do
    tex.print("&"..trim0(result[i]))
    end
    tex.print("\\\\\\end{tblr}\\end{center}")
end    
\end{luacode} 


\begin{document} 

\directlua{fvalues("x^2+1",-3,.5,6)}

\directlua{fvalues("x^2-3*x+1",-3,.5,6)}

\end{document}

Result:

Note that the function must be valid Lua code, so x^2-3x+1 will not work and you need x^2-3*x+1. The * is of course also shown in the LaTeX output in the table so you need to decide if that is ok or if you want to have two arguments, one with the LaTeX syntax and one with the Lua syntax (which may be needed anyway for square roots or fractions etc). Also note that x^2-3*x+1 is not a valid argument for a Lua function so you need "x^2-3*x+1" in the \directlua call.

Here's a version where only the calculations are done by Lua, while the tables are done in the LaTeX part. I used booktabs for the table and also preferred to use directlua instead of the luacode environment to follow David Carlisle's recommendations. I also took inspiration from David's \zz macros to generate the array using the foreach macro zz macro.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document} 
\makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother

\directlua{
function cellx (start,step,n)
return start+step*(n-1)
end
}

\def\calcval#1#2{%
\directlua{
  f = load (([[
        return function (x)
            return (\percentchar s)
        end
    ]]):format ([[#1]]), nil, 't', math) ()
x = #2
tex.print(string.format("\percentchar.2f",f(x)))}
}

\def\fvalues(#1,#2,#3,#4) {%
\def\firstline{$x$}
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,#4}{%
      \xdef\firstline{\firstline &  \directlua{tex.print(cellx(#2,#3,\i))}}%
    }
\def\secondline{$f(x)=#1$}
     \foreach \i in {1,2,...,#4}{%
      \xdef\secondline{\secondline &    
     \calcval{#1}{\directlua{tex.print(cellx(#2,#3,\i))}}}}
     
\begin{tabular}{l*{#4}c}
  \toprule
  \firstline  \\
  \secondline \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
} 

\fvalues(x^2+1,-3,.5,6)
\vspace{12pt}

\fvalues(x^2-3*x+1,-2,.25,8)
\vspace{12pt}

\fvalues(1/exp(x),-5,.25,5)
\end{document}


